# How to groupby one column of DataFrame while it appends corresponding rows in another column and multiplies to the number of itself in its column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, grouping

Imagine we have 2 columns DataFrame, col1 has a unique number while col2 has repeated number like below.

[image]

I want to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# Setup 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':{0:89,1:53,2:97,3:106,4:115,5:56,6:55,7:105,8:71,9:70,10:110},'col2':{0:205,1:205,2:205,3:203,4:203,5:203,6:202,7:201,8:200,9:200,10:198}})

df_new = df.groupby('col2', sort=False)['col1'].apply(list).reset_index()
df_new['col2'] = df_new['col1'].str.len().astype(str) + '*' + df_new.pop('col2').astype(str)
print(df_new)
```

[out]

```
             col1   col2
0    [89, 53, 97]  3*205
1  [106, 115, 56]  3*203
2            [55]  1*202
3           [105]  1*201
4        [71, 70]  2*200
5           [110]  1*198
```

Comment: This returns `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: it shouldn't... `col1` should be a list after groupby . are you calling it properly?

Comment: Yes, you are right I was doing something wrong in my code. Cheers

Comment: col1 is a list of string like ['89','53','97'].

Comment: If you need a list of `str` instead of `int`, use `df_new = df['col1'].astype(str).groupby(df['col2'], sort=False).apply(list).reset_index()` instead

Comment: actually I want int but the result of this query is not.

Comment: It should be... try `print(df_new['col1'].str[0].dtype)` - output: `int64`. `col1` is a list of `int64` dtypes with the solution outlined above

Comment: @MinaBaqerzade do you maybe have non-numeric values in your real data..? what is `print(df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: No, all of them are numeric.

Comment: Then there's no reason why the shouldn't be a list of `int` after `groupby.apply(list)` aggregation..? did you try `print(df_new['col1'].str[0].dtype)`